# How to use Webstorm's local server with a .htaccess file to show pages without .html

Tags: htaccess, webstorm

I have configured the .htaccess file as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url) StackOverflow article. I am now wondering how I get the same functionality for Webstorm as I have setup my links such that they don't have '.html' at the end of them which makes testing a pain.

Answer (score 0):

the built-in webserver provides a basic *.htaccess* support. But `RewriteEngine` directive is not supported, please try using `FallbackResource` instead.
Also, you would need to install '*Apache config (.htaccess) support*' plugin - it's available in *Plugins* repository (**Preferences | Plugins, Install JetBrains plugin...**).

If you need more support (`RewriteEngine` directive, etc.), please vote for [WEB-21869](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21869) youtrack ticket. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications if you are not familiar with youtrack